# Is there any way to get all tags with Taglib Sharp like var_dump in PHP

Tags: c#, taglib, taglib-sharp

For learning more information, I want to get all tags' informations of a media file with Taglib Sharp and for example write to TXT file. Like this:

```
    var media = TagLib.File.Create("media.mp4");
    var_dump(media.Tag);
```

Because I noticed that, the process takes longer when we update media's metadata the first time with Taglib Sharp. After first editing, other editings take shorter. So I wonder, at the first time, is the Taglib Sharp write to media file any specific information about it's identity. If yes, I only want to consider the initial processing times when giving an estimated time to the processing times.

Comment: As with most open source software, its probably light on the documentation, all i can suggest you do is download the source and debug your way through it. That's what the rest of us do

Comment: @TheGeneral, You are absolutely right. But I read all the documents with my limited English in three days, but I could not find anything. I wanted to write here as a last resort.

Comment: I feel you pain, anyway hopefully someone can help you. But i do suggest downloading the source code, you might find what you are looking for

Comment: This is a common obeservation, not at all restricted to TaglibSharp and also not always happening. It seems to happen with files which have either no or few or old tags. When inserting tags at the beginning all the rest must be rewritten; afterwards there seem to be enough buffers to avoid that.

Comment: In addition to @TaW's answer: Many libraries write some kind of buffer. If such a buffer exists, new or changed data can be filled in much faster. If not, all the tags must be rewritten. And for your question in the title: NO, there is no easy way to get all Tags, Frames in all versions. You have to loop through all the possible values by yourself.

Comment: @PeterCo, Thank you, my friends. Yes, it is painful but nothing like that. I sat down and prepaired everything myself. I will share it here very soon. At least, those who need it then is benefited.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I *think* what you want is:

```html
<variablename>.Tag.EndTag
```

This gives me what seems like an exhaustive list of all possible tags, with their values.